# Bash script nohup execution

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script that checks that there are 6 FFmpeg scripts running and if there isn't it kills the renaming FFmpeg pids.

My problem is that the kill command "kill -9 $i" works but the code doesn't continue to nohup code.

Here is my output:

```
Service Count 6 currently running 5
Some services has failed
Killing pid 11794
Killing pid 11795
Killing pid 11805
Killed
```

I'm assuming the "Killed" means my script stopped.  If I remove the "kill -9 $1", the code continues to the nohup command. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

arrSize=6;
array=(`ps aux | grep -i ffmpeg | awk '{print $2}'`);

# Array Length
echo "Service Count $arrSize currently running ${#array[@]}"
# echo "Length ${#array[@]}"

if (( ${#array[@]} < $arrSize ))
then

    echo Some services has failed
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo "Killing pid $i";
        kill -9 $i
    done

    echo Staring camera 1
    nohup ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel panic -i "http://electcam1.site.com/mjpg/video.mjpg" -q 0 -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -s 1366x768 http://127.0.0.1:8081/secret & 
    exit
    # sleep 1
    echo Starting camera 2
    nohup ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel panic -i "http://electcam2.site.com/mjpg/video.mjpg" -q 0 -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -s 1366x768 http://127.0.0.1:8083/secret &
    # exit


else
    echo All services are running;
fi
```

Comment: Do not `ps aux | grep`. `Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?` you are killing yourself. Does your script has `"ffmpeg` in the name? On the other side, consider using some _real_ service management, like systemd, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: yup, it was because I had FFmpeg in the script name.  Thanks.  I have never used systems so I will have too look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `ps aux | grep` except then for printing pretty-looking human readable lines. To find pid of a command use `pgrep`. To kill these commands, use `pkill`.

```
IFS=$'\n' array=($(pgrep '^ffmpeg$'))
```

Check your script with http://shellcheck.net . Do not use backticks ` - use `$(..)` instead. Remember to quote variable expansions.

To control services I suggest to use your workstation service manager (that's literally been designed to manage services...), on modern unix-es that's systemd. If the *goal* is to write it by yourself, still use existing utils, like supervisord. If the goal is not to use it, remember that by killing *all* ffmpeg on your workstation you will accidentally kill other unrelated ffmpeg instances. Instead a common way is to save the pid to a file (typically in /var/run/something.pid file) and then use that file to determine if the service is running. See how services management looks like ex. in openrc. But at best use your native service manager instead of reinventing the wheel.